# panic interface conversion interface {} is float64 not int64

Tags: go, types, jwt, go-fiber

I am getting the following error

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is float64, not int64
```

I am not sure where float64 is coming from here
I have type set to int64 but not sure where float64 came from

```
type AccessDetails struct {
    AccessUuid   string  `json:"access_uuid"`
    Email        string  `json:"email"`
    Refresh      int64    `json:"refresh"`
    Expiry       int64   `json:"expiry"`
    Permission   string  `json:"permission"`
    Scope        string  `json:"scope"`
}

func GetAccessDetails(c *fiber.Ctx) (*AccessDetails, error) {
    ad := &AccessDetails{}

    cookie := c.Cookies("access_token")

    var err error
    token, err := jwt.Parse(cookie, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(os.Getenv("ACCESS_SECRET")), nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    payload := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    
    ad.Email = payload["sub"].(string)
    ad.AccessUuid = payload["access_uuid"].(string)
    ad.Refresh = payload["refresh"].(int64)
    ad.Expiry = payload["exp"].(int64)
    ad.Permission = payload["permission"].(string)
    ad.Scope = payload["scope"].(string)

    return ad, nil
}
```

The error seems to be from the line `ad.Refresh = payload["refresh"].(int64)`
I think i just need to know how to convert types from float64 to int64 or vice versa for interfaces {}

I have tried everything to change the type back to int64 but i get one error or the other and now need help to move forward

here is example of what the payload data looks like from the cookie after it is jwt decoded

```
{
  "access_uuid": "c307ac76-e591-41d0-a638-6dcc2f963704",
  "exp": 1642130687,
  "permission": "user",
  "refresh": 1642734587,
  "sub": "test3@example.com"
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you attempted to convert from float64 to int64?

Comment: i tried this for example `ad.Refresh = int64(payload["refresh"])` and others..i just want to have int64 that is all

Comment: `int64(payload["refresh"].(float64))` -- [jwt.MapClaims](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#MapClaims) is a `map[string]interface{}` and presumably it is unmarshaled from json using [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.5) which, by default, unmarshals json numbers into `interface{}` as `float64`.

Comment: Explaining @mkopriva's comment, you must first perform type assertion to the actual type, and then perform a conversion to the desired type.

Comment: @mkopriva does not work...tried what you mentioned `ad.Refresh = int64(payload["refresh"].(float64))`

Comment: @uberrebu what does "does not work" mean? what error are you getting?

Comment: getting same error still `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is float64, not int64`

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. You're not doing what I've suggested. See [here](https://go.dev/play/p/sXTVwQH9y7S), no panic.

Comment: can you post as answer what i need to do? @mkopriva

Comment: I assume, after you fixed `refresh`, you're now getting the same panic for `exp`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241057/discussion-between-uberrebu-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```golang
ad.Refresh = int64(payload["refresh"].(float64))
ad.Expiry = int64(payload["exp"].(float64))
```

You need to first [assert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the accurate dynamic type of the interface value and then, if successful, you can [convert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) it to your desired type.

Note that the reason the interface values are `float64` is because that's the default setting of the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.5) decoder when unmarshaling JSON numbers into `interface{}` values.

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of
> these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```